# Multi Project Template folder structure incorrect

Tags: asp.net, .net, templates, visual-studio-2012

So i am trying to build a Multi Project template and when i set it up the folder structure is coming out incorrectly (Not how microsoft does it when creating projects) and it's messing things up like the *Packages* folder and *References* folder.

This is current Structure:

```
Solution Folder
-Solution File
-Folder (Solution Name)
 --Packages
 --References
 --Project1 Folder
 --Project2 Folder
```

I am wanting it to have the same structure that .NET does automatically:

```
Solution Folder
-Solution File
-References Folder
-Packages Folder
-Project1 Folder
-Project2 Folder
```

Here is my vstemplate:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>ASP Solution Template</Name>
    <Description>This is the Solution Template for ASP Applications</Description>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent BuildOnLoad="true">
    <ProjectCollection>
      <SolutionFolder Name="References">
      </SolutionFolder>
      <SolutionFolder Name="packages">
      </SolutionFolder>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$">
        ASPTemplate\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
      <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.ClassLibrary">
        ClassLibrary\MyTemplate.vstemplate
      </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at **dotnet new** custom templates. I had the same problem and this was a nice easy solution.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/create-custom-template

- Create your solution and put your files and/or projects where you like, I'll call the solution *MySolution*
- Add folders, projects, whatever you like
- Create a folder at the top level by the solution called .template.config
- Create a json file in that .template.config called template.json

The template.json attributes can be found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates

Example template.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/template",
    "author": "Your goodself",
    "classifications": [ "C#", "Awesome", "etc" ],
    "identity": "MySolution",
    "name": "Empty MySolution",
    "shortName": "mysolution",
    "sourceName": "MySolution",
    "tags": {
        "language": "C#"
    },
}
```

*sourceName* is important, that is used to name your project new project and rename everything.

To see what templates you already have do:

```
dotnet new -l
```

To add your new template the above do:

```
dotnet new -i <fully qualified solution folder>
```

eg. dotnet new -i c:\dev\MySolution

You should then see your name in a:

```
dotnet new -l
```

That's it, ready to use!

Go to a fresh folder and type:

```
dotnet new mysolution -n MySolutionFromTemplate
```

You will then see all the folders, files and everything named as expected

---

Finally if you want to delete the template do:

```
dotnet new -u c:\dev\MySolution
```

NOTE: You will probably need this in your nuget repo. There are instructions how to do this here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/create-custom-template

Comment: This one should be the acepted answer. Also the Microsoft Docs are very good for this, with a 3 part tutorial: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-item-template

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to add solution folders in the parent solution folder with vstemplates.

**However**, you could try adding a wizard to your template that enables you to run custom code when a user creates a project from a template.

Follow the instructions [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms185301.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte80.solutionfolder.addsolutionfolder.aspx), but basically you do something like this:

1. Implement the [IWizard interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.aspx) in a ClassLibrary-project and use [EnvDTE80](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0e105c68.aspx) to create the folders:

   ```
   public class MyWizard : IWizard
   {
       public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
       {
           // Pseudo-code
           var dte = (DTE2)automationObject;
           var solution = (Solution2)dte.Solution;

           solution.AddSolutionFolder("References");
       }

       // Default implementations of IWizard here (return true's and do nothing's)
   }
   ```
2. Modify your vstemplate to use the wizard:

   ```
   <VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="ProjectGroup">
     <TemplateData />
     <TemplateContent BuildOnLoad="true" /> <!-- Remove the SolutionFolder elements -->

     <WizardExtension>
       <Assembly>CustomWizard, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=fa3902f409bb6a3b</Assembly>
       <FullClassName>CustomWizard.MyWizard</FullClassName>
     </WizardExtension>

   </VSTemplate>
   ```

Then the code should be running when you create a project with your new template.

*Hope this helps you somehow.*